# AWS Beanstalk - Worker env is not processing background jobs after nginx force SSL config changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I am working on a `Ruby on Rails` application and it is deployed on **AWS Beanstalk**. My Beanstalk application has two environments:

```
- Web Env
  - config:
    - Ruby 2.4.3
    - Rails 5.1.4
    - Puma as App server
    - Nginx as Web Server
    - Uses active_elastic_job

- Worker Env
  - config:
    - Ruby 2.4.3
    - Rails 5.1.4
    - Puma as App server
    - Nginx as Web server
    - Uses Amazon - SQS
    - Uses active_elastic_job
```

Both `Envs` uses the same repo/codebase and my app was fully configured.

Last week, I came to know that my application is not force redirecting to `https`. Though, I was able to access my site with `https` but when accessed via `http` or accessing directly via the domain name was not redirecting me to secure site.

I came across with this link https://gist.github.com/petelacey/e35c98f9a35063a89fa9 and after deploying this file using `.ebextensions` on Web Env, I am now able to redirect to `https` --- Till here no problem

But, when I tried deploying the same **Running version** to my **Worker Env**, my background jobs have stopped working

To troubleshoot that, I `ssh` into my Worker env and inspected below files:

`/var/log/nginx/error.log` -- Nothing suspicious found

`/var/log/puma/puma.log` -- Nothing suspicious found

`/var/log/aws-sqsd/default.log` -- I see lots of `http-err`

`/var/log/amazon/ssm/errors.log`

```
2018-05-08 11:28:19 ERROR [HandleAwsError @ awserr.go.48] [instanceID=i-YYYYYYYYYY] [MessagingDeliveryService] [Association] error when calling AWS APIs. error details - AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/role/i-YYYYYYYYYY is not authorized to perform: ssm:ListInstanceAssociations on resource: arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:instance/i-YYYYYYYYYY
  status code: 400, request id: ''
2018-05-08 11:28:19 ERROR [HandleAwsError @ awserr.go.48] [instanceID=i-YYYYYYYYYY] [MessagingDeliveryService] [Association] error when calling AWS APIs. error details - AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-YYYYYYYYYY is not authorized to perform: ssm:ListAssociations on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:*
  status code: 400, request id: ''
2018-05-08 11:28:19 ERROR [ProcessAssociation @ processor.go.157] [instanceID=i-YYYYYYYYYY] [MessagingDeliveryService] [Association] Unable to load instance associations, unable to retrieve associations unable to retrieve associations AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-YYYYYYYYYY is not authorized to perform: ssm:ListAssociations on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:*
  status code: 400, request id: ''
```

Before rolling this nginx proxy file, everything was working fine. I am not sure what I did wrong?

Two things I am trying immediately:

1. Override `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` on my worker env manually with the old `proxy.conf` file I have.
2. Restart nginx to see if job/s are back to normal

But few points I would like to point here:

1. Both the ENVs are not supposed to use the same Running version?
2. If my above approach works, that means I will have 2 different proxy files on different ENV. In future, if I deploy to my worker ENV, it will override the custom one. Can this be skipped?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. My friend told me to handle this in below way:

**STEP:1** inside `config/environments/production.rb`

change `config.force_ssl = true` to `config.force_ssl = 'web'.eql?(ENV.fetch('EB_ENV', 'web'))`

**STEP:2** Define `EB_ENV`environment variable as `web` for **Web ENV** or `worker`/whatever you like for **Worker ENV**

Thanks friend! Much appreciated.